# How to fetch only numerical values from table field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table which stores student details like name,Phone no,address and other basic details.In address field stores student address like : ABC apartment;Lat:21.1111;Long:71.1111.Now I want to write a MySQL select query that gives me only 21.1111 and 71.1111 as result.which matching function should i use to get the required result.

Comment: *query that gives me only 21.1111 and 71.1111* AS two separate columns in one output row? *student address like : ABC apartment;Lat:21.1111;Long:71.1111* Does this column's value matches this pattern `'{some words};Lat:21.1111;Long:71.1111'` always?

Comment: No.I just want lat value and long value to pass it for other part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`address`, 'Lat:', -1), ';', 1) AS Latitude,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`address`, 'Long:', -1), ';', 1) AS Longtude
FROM student_details;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Akina Perfect answer.